# how to manipulate textwidth of footnote?

Tags: footnotes, geometry, marginnote

I am using custom margins so I can include figures in the right margin and references in the footer. I would like the footer to span the linewidth of the text body and the margin.

Here is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[left=36pt,right=233.28pt,top=2cm,bottom=2cm, marginparwidth=66mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}

\section{A title goes here}

\lipsum[1-2]

\marginnote{\footnotesize An image goes here in the right margin.}

\lipsum[1-2]\footnote{A footnote goes here in the footer and should stretch right across the page to include the right margin.}

\end{document}
```

I have google for a \footnotewidth but haven't had any luck with that search.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[left=36pt,right=233.28pt,top=2cm,bottom=2cm, marginparwidth=66mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}

\section{A title goes here}

\lipsum[1-2]

\marginnote{\footnotesize An image goes here in the right margin.}

\lipsum[1-2]\footnote{\hsize=\dimexpr\columnwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax
A footnote goes here in the footer and should stretch right across the page to include the right margin.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So using the tex primitive `\hsize` allows page breaking to go right? Interesting

Comment: @VincentKuhlmann yes as does Seven's less conventional version with \rightskip

Comment: Thanks! That works well.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I add a negative `\rightskip` inside each footnote.  The actual value is `-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[left=36pt,right=233.28pt,top=2cm,bottom=2cm, marginparwidth=66mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\let\svfootnote\footnote
\def\footnote#1{\svfootnote{\rightskip\dimexpr
  -\marginparsep-\marginparwidth #1}}
\begin{document}

\section{A title goes here}

\lipsum[1-2]

\marginnote{\footnotesize An image goes here in the right margin. Adding
i i i i more to test margination.  An image goes here in the right margin. 
Adding  more to test margination.  An image goes here in the right margin.
Adding more to test margination.  }

\lipsum[1]\footnote{A footnote goes here in the footer and should stretch right across the page to include the right margin.  Adding a bit more
to check the margination.}

\lipsum[2]\footnote{Testing another footnote.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is a very efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LaTeX boxes to claim more width. Note that I am using `\rlap` which sets the width of the box to 0. This is just to avoid the "overfull" box warning. It's a bit hacky, but hey, it's LaTeX.

```
\newcommand{\widefootnote}[1]{%
    \footnote{\rlap{\parbox{\dimexpr\paperwidth-72pt\relax}{#1}}}%
}
```

[image: Output of answer code]

Now use `\widefootnote` instead of `\footnote`. Alternatively you could do

```
\let\oldfootnote\footnote

\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{%
    \oldfootnote{\rlap{\parbox{\dimexpr\paperwidth-72pt\relax}{#1}}}%
}
```

and use `\footnote` everywhere instead.

Comment: this will prevent the footnote breaking over the page (some people may consider that a benefit:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ah, that's right yes. It's all about exorbitant long footnotes here haha

Comment: you would also want to use `[t]` otherwise (as shown in your image) the footnote number is weirdly placed

Comment: @DavidCarlisle indeed. Forgot top-alignment was not default. I don't get why people are so crazy about center alignments

Comment: Thanks, Vincent.